# Pattern and Matcher java problem, last element is null

Tags: java

I'm facing a problem that I can't understand why my last element in console is null after using matcher and pattern. And also i can't get rid off , and [ ]

This is how my file looks:

```
[Programuotojo vardas: Jonas, pavarde: Jonaitis, amzius: 21, programavimo kalba: Java]
```

And my code:

```
private void vartotojoIvedimasIsFailo() {
    File FILE = new File(pasirenkantDarbuotojusIsFailo);
    if (FILE.exists() && FILE.length() > 0) {
        try {
            Scanner SC = new Scanner(FILE);
            for (int i = 0; i < FILE.length(); i++) {
                if (SC.hasNextLine()) {
                    String storage = SC.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("ID: " + i + " " + storage);
                }
            }
            Scanner SI = new Scanner(System.in);
            int vartotojoPasirinkimas = Integer.parseInt(SI.nextLine());
            String line = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(pasirenkantDarbuotojusIsFailo)).get(vartotojoPasirinkimas);
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":(.*?),(.*?)");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            String[] output = new String[4];
            int i = 0;
            while (matcher.find()) {
                output[i++] = matcher.group(1).trim().replace(",", "");
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
```

Last println looks like: [Jonas, Jonaitis, 21, null]

Comment: You are declaring an Array of String[] of 4. This matcher is just finding "Jonas", "Jonaitis" and "21". You are iterating in this array and filling the first 3 elements, so the last one is null.

Comment: Your regex looks for text between a `:` and a `,`, but the last value doesn't have a comma after it. Try `":([^,\\]]*)"` instead.

Comment: Arrays.toString outputs any array you give it with `[`, `]`, and `,`

Comment: @gfos oh yea.. legit -_-

Comment: @Andreas no, he said "i can't get rid off , and [ ]". If he knew, he would have done something about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are declaring an String array called output of 4 elements. When you are doing this, all this values are null:

**[null, null, null, null]**

In this lines:

```
  while (matcher.find()) {
            output[i++] = matcher.group(1).trim().replace(",", "");
        }
```

You are changing this array values, in this case, you are filling the results like this:

**["Jonas", "Jonaitis", "21", null]**

You are missing the last one, that's the reason because is null.

Other thing... if you have more than 4 matches, this will cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Consider using a list to do the output:

```
List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println(matcher.groupCount());
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1).trim());
        output.add(matcher.group(1).trim().replace(",", ""));

    }
    output.forEach(System.out::println);
```